# Getting error while adding labels to barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, label

[image: Image showing Barplot]

I'm plotting the distribution plot for getting counts for number of tweets for different polarity categories. I'm drawing the plot in ggplot2 as given below but getting an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'y' not found`. Please help.

```
ggplot(sentimentdf, aes(x=emotionfit)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=..count.., fill=emotionfit)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Dark2") + labs(x="Emotion Categories", y="Number of Tweets", title="Emotion Classification") +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label = y))
```

Comment: Die you declare the variable y anywhere before in your Code? Otherwise this: geom_text(aes(label = y)) does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you wanted to continue to use `..count..` for your labels instead of `y`, you could do it like this:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = as.factor(cyl), fill = as.factor(cyl))) +
    geom_bar() +
    geom_label(aes(label = ..count..), stat = "count", color = "white") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")
```

[image]

`geom_bar()` uses `stat = "count"` by default, but `geom_label()` requires you to explicitly change it, since `stat = "identity"` is it's default.

Comment: I tried by providing the details you mentioned Nathan but it still didn't work.

Comment: hmmm, are you able to reproduce my figure? maybe check `sessionInfo()`, I'm running `ggplot2_2.2.0`. happy to help